# DSE: Geo location i.e latitude and longitude is stored as different fields in cassandra

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I'm upgrading from Apache Cassandra to Datastax Cassandra. Planning to use the location search feature on one of my tables.

Current table looks something like below

```
CREATE TABLE tweets (
   id INT PRIMARY KEY,
   user TEXT,
   body TEXT,
   time TIMESTAMP,
   latitude FLOAT,
   longitude FLOAT
);
```

In the example Datastax Solr [config](https://github.com/PatrickCallaghan/datastax-geospatial-demo/blob/master/src/main/resources/solr/postcode_geo.xml), I see that latitude and longitude are expected to part of the same column. Is there a way where I can index 
latitude and longitude separately so that Solr can understand ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you can achieve this by using [Field Input Transformer](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/search/fieldInputOutputTransformerApi.html) (FIT) - it allows to transform document that is submitted to Solr, so you can take both coordinates & create one single field from it.  Please check the linked documentation - it has sample code, that shouldn't be very hard to implement.

P.S. Instead of LatLong type you may look to [RPT (RecursivePrefixTree)](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/spatial-search.html) instead - it could be more efficient. I also have [an example](https://github.com/alexott/datastax-vehicle-demo/blob/code-optimizations/src/main/resources/cql/create_schema.cql#L16) how this field type could be configured in DSE (although I'm using the DSE's `PointType` inside DSE Core).

Answer (score 0):

> For Spatial Queries in solr you need to store latitude and longitude comma separated in the field having type location.
>
> if you try to put only single value in field type location it will gives you error, if you want use solr's Spatial search then you have to store both as comma separated in location type only.
>
> You can store both values in different field using data type either pfloat or pdouble, but you can not use solr's Spatial search functionality for finding nearest distance.